# PyQt: Get current tab number

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

Is there a way to get the currently selected tab's number/index? I have a dictionary of tabs but I need to be able to get the currently active one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call [`currentIndex()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtabwidget.html#currentIndex) on the TabWidget to get the currently selected tab.